# How to create a list that is nested under another list?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, nested-lists

I am trying to make a nested list that is under another list from a four-column data frame. This is a snippet of my dataframe (that has 661,599 rows in total).

`df`:

| Regulator | TG | MOA | likelihood |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AATF | RYR1 | 0.00685 | 0.5924 |
| AATF | IRF2 | 0.02616 | 0.8229 |
| AATF | SCIMP | 0.04981 | 0.0819 |
| AATF | GLO1 | 0.04546 | 0.5160 |
| ABCA1 | A1CF | 0.52321 | 0.6133 |
| ABCA1 | WASHC4 | 0.99986 | 0.9823 |
| ABCA1 | STPG4 | 0.99921 | 0.6293 |
| ABCA1 | IGSF23 | 0.53167 | 0.8716 |

I need the format as the r package that I am using required certain list format to actually be able to calculate the results I need.

The results that I wanted to achieve looked like this:
[image: Expected format]
where the outermost list is from the 'Regulator' column, in which that list has two lists nested under each 'Regulator', namely 'tfmode' and 'likelihood'. 'likelihood' is from the likelihood column, while 'tfmode' is a list that contains 'TG' and 'MOA'.

```
#attempt number 1
first_list <- split(df, df$Regulator)
second_list <- lapply(first_list, function(x) x[!names(x) %in% c("Regulator")])
```

[image: results from my attempt number one]

```
#attempt number two
another_list <- list(TFMODE = list(df$`TG`, df$MOA), likelihood = df$likelihood)
```

[image: results from my attempt number two]

I feel like it would be easier to work from attempt number one, so here are my questions, feel free to answer any of them and I will try to work on it:

1. How to access the columns of dataframe (TG & MOA) that is nested in the list under each regulators? *I am thinking that a for loop might be the answer for the massive dataframe I have, but I have no idea how to access the columns inside each regulators.*

   I tried: `second_list[["ABCA1"$TG]]` and `second_list[1][2]` but both had the same `$<NA> NULL` result
2. How to bring the three columns (still dataframe) to a list while being under each regulators (already a list)?

Any comment or suggestions are very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: (1) Nest the list access: `second_list$AATF$TG`

Comment: You might find package {data.tree} helpful, both for conversion from tabular to hierarchical data ("trees") and back, and for traversing / manipulating trees: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html